# Difference Quotients on Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, poissons-equation

I want to define "the difference quotient of a differential form $ \omega $ in the direction of the vector field $ X $" on a Riemannian manifold.  Let's call this object, if it can be defined, $ \nabla_X^h \omega $, where $ h > 0 $ is the "step size" and $ \omega $ is a tensor or differential form.  My questions are, can this object be defined in such a way that it has the properties one would want: $ \omega \in W^{1,2}(\bigwedge^k M) $ if and only if $ \| \nabla^h_X \omega \|_{L^2} $ remains bounded for small $ h $ and all smooth vector fields $ X $ with $ \| X \|_{L^\infty} < 1 $ (say), and hopefully an integration by parts formula such as

$ \int_M{ \nabla^h_X \omega \wedge * \varphi} = -\int_M{ \omega \wedge * \nabla^{-h}_X \varphi } $

My question is, does any such operation $ \nabla^h_X \omega $ exist?

In case the reader is curious, my goal is, I'd like to write a "quick" and "easy" argument that the Poisson Equation $ \Delta \omega = f $ on a Riemannian Manifold $ M $ (where $ \Delta $ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator) is solvable for $ f \in L^2(\bigwedge^k M) $ with $ \omega \in W^{2,2} $.  I've read the proof by Warner; and I've read proofs of elliptic regularity in places like Evans; however, I believe it can be done more elegantly in the case of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a closed compact riemannian manifold.  This seems to be the object I need to complete the proof of regularity.

Comment: I like the idea here, but I think of a difference quotient as $Q(a) = \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$. That requires that the two things in the numerator can be subtracted. That works for items in $\Bbb R^n$, but here, it looks as if you'll be evaluating $\omega(u) - \omega(v)$, where $u$ and $v$ are distinct (but nearby) points of your manifold. One of these acts on tangent/cotangent vectors at $u$, the other on tangent/cotangent vectors at $v$. The obvious way to get from $v$ from $u$ is to run out $h$ units along the flow defined by $X$; that's locally a diffeomorphism.

Comment: But how to get vectors at $u$ to be vectors at $v$? Apply the derivative of that diffeomorphism? I suppose it could work, but the "integration by parts" seems like it might be hard to prove, or only true up to $O(h^2)$ or something.

Comment: "difference quotient of $\omega$ in the direction of $X$" seems to look an awful lot like the definition of the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X\omega$...

Comment: $\omega(0)=\omega$, $\dot{\omega}(t)=\mathcal{L}_X\omega(t)$, $\nabla_X^h\omega=\frac{1}{h}(\omega(h)-\omega(0))$?

Comment: Hmm.  I was thinking when I posed the question that I probably wanted to use the Levi Civita connection to define it.  But it might not be necessary.  I'll try this and update.